# How to correctly send data from javascript (jQuery) application to Rails backend (Heroku)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, safari

i am working on a javascript (jQuery) app that collects user data (name, gender, birthday, etc) and sends it off to a Rails app hosted at Heroku.  The Rails reads the JSON from the request and is supposed to create a new record.  my code is as follows

```
params = {};
params.session_user = {};

var e = {
    "username"    :    localStorage.getItem("UN"),
    "gender"      :    gender,
    "birthdate"   :    birthdate,
    "session_id"  :    getSessionID(),
};
params.session_user = e;
$.post("https://***.herokuapp.com/session_users", params);
```

This works for Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and IE, but does NOT work with Safari.  Safari continues to say that the POST request was cancelled and no records are ever created on the database.

similarly, the jQuery app also collects usage data on each page of the app, called focus_events.  I used the same format,

```
var e = {
    "timestamp"  : (new Date).toUTCString(),
    "focus_type" : type,
    "page"       : page_id,
    "problem_set": problem_set_id,
    "session_id" : getSessionID(),
  }
 params={};
 params.focus_event={};
 params.focus_event=e;
 $.post("https://***.herokuapp.com/focus_events",params);
```

and this works most of the time.  But occasionally, and across all browsers, the POST request will also show up as cancelled.  any help would be greatly appreciated with both this and the Safari issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the problem.  posting answer here for posterity.  $.post() (which is jusat a wrapper for ajax()) defaults to sending requests asynchronously.  As my requests were being sent when the user clicked the next page button, the requests were being cut off when the browser loaded the new page. changing my $.post(...) to

```
$.ajax({
    url    :    "https://***.herokuapp/controller_name",
    data   :    params,
    type   :    'POST';
    async  :    false,
});
```

works beautifully.  Solved both the Safari issue and the focus_event issue.  Note that when sending synchronously and depending on how responsive the server is, you may need to be patient and sit and wait for the requests to complete.  The browser will not load the next page until the requests are completed.